# Доброжелательство и доброжелательность синонимы? взаимозаменяемы?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

> Я не люблю конфликты и всякую напряжёнку. Я за мир во всем мире. Вот
>   хотя бы в радиусе трёх метров вокруг мне жизненно необходимо **пространство
>   доброжелательства**. И думаю, что если бы каждый старался вот тупо для
>   ближнего, то это было бы хорошо. Иногда же достаточно просто смотреть
>   на людей и хорошего им желать, уже настроение вокруг меняется. Другое
>   поле **образовывается**, говорят, даже квантовые частицы это понимают.

Можно отставить "образовывается" вместо привычного мне "образуется"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Доброжелательство и доброжелательность**

ДОБРОЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНЫЙ,  **Проявляющий** доброе отношение, расположение к кому-, чему-л., готовый содействовать благополучию кого-л. Д. человек. // **Выражающий** участие, расположение. Д. смех. Д-ая улыбка. Д-ые слова. Д-ое отношение.  **Доброжелательность**, -и; ж. **Д. к людям.** **Доброжелательство**, -а; ср. **Проявить** д. по отношению к кому-, чему-л. **Чувствовать чьё-л. д**.

Доброжелательность – это качество. Доброжелательство – проявление этого качества. Тогда выбираем **пространство доброжелательства**, в котором **проявляется** доброжелательное отношение.

2) ***Другое поле образовывается...***

Надо оставить, подчеркивается постоянно протекающий процесс. В настоящем времени существует две формы несов. вида, но форма ***образуется*** может выражать и сов. вид. Такое понимание надо исключить.

1. ОБРАЗОВАТЬСЯ, -зуется; св. **(наст. св. и нсв.**). 1.  Получиться, появиться, возникнуть. .**<Образовываться,**

Форма "образуются" может иметь разное грамматическое значение вида, и можно, к примеру, сказать: пещеры образуются постоянно(что делают, несов. вид) или пещеры образуются в будущем (что сделают, сов. вид).

Можно посмотреть ответы http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2960244-kak-pravilno-obrazujutsja-ili-obrazovyvajutsja-pochemu.html